# Clojure :: lint-like hints

Tags: clojure

I hunted a bug today that ultimately resulted from the following snippet somewhere in my code (where I was trying to filter for only "PRIMARY KEY" constraints in a list):

```
(filter #(= (% :constraint_type "PRIMARY KEY")) aListOfconstraints)
```

Instead of the correct:

```
(filter #(= (% :constraint_type) "PRIMARY KEY") aListOfconstraints)
```

I.e. the bug was the combined effect of a map taking a default argument in case the key is not found, as in:

```
({:a 1 :b 2} :a 0)
```

... and the equal functions accepting only one argument and returning true:

```
(= 1) ; evals to true
```

Is there any tool I could have used instead that would have prompted me to this sort of valid, but suspicious code? Or perhaps some best practice I am not aware of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can look to [kibit](https://github.com/jonase/kibit/) - tool that tries to perform static analysis of clojure code, using rules built on top of `core.logic`. It should be not so hard to add new rules, but this tool also have limitations - see project's description.

Answer (score 5):

The best practice you're looking for would be a unit test checking the proper behavior of your code.

A for the lint tool you could take a look at [Eastwood](https://github.com/jonase/eastwood), but in your case it would be difficult to provide a custom check, that could be used widely.

Answer (score 3):

If you have this kind of problems it's better to use right indentation. In your case

```
(filter #(= (% :constraint_type)
            "PRIMARY KEY")
        aListOfconstraints)
```

And if you have

```
(filter #(= (% :constraint_type "PRIMARY KEY")
            )
        aListOfconstraints)
```

you obviously can notice a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Eastwood, mentioned in an earlier answer, is now capable as of early 2014 of catching your particular problem, and several other kinds.  Check it out: https://github.com/jonase/eastwood